# Python selenium handle windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium

Trying to make a bot for a website too chat in with a lot of accounts.

```
for x in range(0,2):
    project_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    chromedriver_path = os.path.join(project_dir, 'chromedriver.exe')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
    driver.get("https://*********/login")

    user = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="username"]""")
    user.send_keys(username[x])

    passs = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[2]/input""")
    passs.send_keys("***")

    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[3]/button""").click()


    driver.get("https://***/channel")


x = driver.find_element_by_class_name("js-chat_input")
while True:
    enter = raw_input("Chat: ")
    for i in range(0, 2):
        g= driver.window_handles[i]
        x.send_keys(enter)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button.primary.float-right").click()
```

I want to make it so it will switch windows too enter what I enter in chat, if there is a simpler way that you know of I'll be glad to try it.

my error is

```
", line 32, in <module>
    g= driver.window_handles[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, I have updated the for loop that you were using. Now the for loop will iterate based on your number of windows.

```
x = driver.find_element_by_class_name("js-chat_input")
while True:
    enter = raw_input("Chat: ")
    for i in range(0, len(driver.window_handles)):
        g= driver.window_handles[i]
        x.send_keys(enter)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button.primary.float-right").click()
```

Comment: It got rid of the error, but only one of my account is typing

Comment: They both login fine, but when I try to enter something in chat, only my one types

Comment: Yeah it's correct only one account will type and send the chat in, im testing it with two accounts

Answer (score 0):

where is window_handles and how big is it.

I would debug your code by commenting out everything in the while True loop and printing the length of driver.window_handles

```
while True:
    #enter = raw_input("Chat: ")
    #for i in range(0, 2):
        #g= driver.window_handles[i]
        #x.send_keys(enter)
        #driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button.primary.float-right").click()

    print(len(driver.window_handles))
```

this will give you a start as to why your index is out of range when running your iteration